# responsive css line mix with letters

Tags: css

I'm working on fixing this site http://zygi.loginet.gr and having problem with the horizontal line @home page above the products. When i make the window smaller line is getting mixed with letters, how can i do it?

```
    .page-header, .topten-view h4, .xselling h3 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}



.page-header, .topten-view h4 {
    margin: 2em auto!important;
}
.page-header h2  {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;


}
.topten-view h4:before, .topten-view h4:after, .xselling h3:before, .xselling h3:after {
    background: #90AF5F;
}
.page-header:before, .page-header:after{
    background: #000;
}
.page-header:before, .page-header:after,
.topten-view h4:before, .topten-view h4:after,
.xselling h3:before, .xselling h3:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
}
.page-header:before,
.topten-view h4:before,
.xselling h3:before {
    left: 0;
}
.page-header:after,
.topten-view h4:after,
.xselling h3:after {
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code with h4 heading tag:

```
.topten-view h4 {
    padding-left: 31%;
    padding-right: 31%;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.